# Why the button width is great than inputs, they are all in the same form

Tags: css

i have a React code that is doing simple form:

```
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login-form">
      <label>
        Username:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={username}
          onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
          className="input"
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Password:
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
          className="input"
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit" className="button">Login</button>
    </form>
```

The fact is when i'm styling this code i get the witdh button is greater than inputs but i don't understand what i'm doing bad, because its giving 100% width in both elements.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  .login-form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  
  .label {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  .input {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

So, what i'm doing wrong? I thought the button width 100% would have been adapt to class form

Example:
[image]

Comment: While I've removed the React aspect to put a demo together ([JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/syvewn0u/)) the posted CSS doesn't reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: `width:100%` means 100% of the parent elements' width. The button takes the width of the form and the inputs take the width of the label, which might not be set correctly.

Comment: @Esger true.. so how can i give my button the same width of the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.login-form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: min-content;
}

.label {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.input {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} class="login-form">
  <label>Username:
    <input type="text"
          class="input"/>
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>Password:
      <input type="password"
          class="input"/>
    </label>
  <br />
  <button type="submit" class="button">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I added a few lines of css for you... maybe it helps.